# Refresh observable based on behavior change in Angular (RxJS)

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a way to refresh a collection of observables which are exposed to the template in an ASYNC manner, once a user changes a variable/property in the site.

The scenario is simple, we have multiple accounts that our CSR's are looking after, they log in with a profile and then are presented the opportunity to change/view a different account.

When the account is changes, I emit the account change via BehaviorSubject and subscribe to the event elsewhere in my application, for argument sake, /users.

In the users component, I have a few Observables, representing the data on this page (various data end points) and I subscribe to them in the template with the "async" pipe.

I want to update those observables when I receive confirmation that the account selection has been made.

I've looked into adding behaviour subjects to the web services, but this does not work. Marking the page for changes or triggering a change check on the page also has no effect.

For reference:

```js
users$: Observable<User[]>;

/** onInit **/
this.users$ = this.service.retrieveusers(); // returns Observable<User[]>

this.accountService.changed.subscribe(x => {
   this.users$ = this.service.retrieveusers(); // this does not work because it's unaware of changes
});
```

I tried wrapping the call in a new BehaviorSubject based on some posts I read but has no effect either;

```js
update = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

/** onInit **/
this.users$ = this.service.retrieveusers(); // returns Observable<User[]>

this.accountService.changed.subscribe(x => {
   this.update.next(true);
});

this.update.subscribe(x => {
   this.users$ = this.service.retrieveusers(); // this does not work because it's unaware of changes
});
```

The above also has no effect.

How would I go about updating users$ when accountService.changed is fired?

Answer (score 0):

Your really close you just missing the pipe and mergeMap.

```
/** onInit **/
this.users$ =  this.accountService.changed.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => this.service.retrieveusers())
)
```

If we assume changed will emit a value initially then the above code should work. If changed isn't going to emit a value initially then we need a make a use RXJS to emit a initial value to trigger the service call to retrieveuser(). There are a number of different ways to accomplish this.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith

```
/** onInit **/
this.users$ =  this.accountService.changed.pipe(
    startsWith({}),
    mergeMap(() => this.service.retrieveusers())
)
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat

```
/** onInit **/
 this.users$ =  concat(of({}), this.accountService.changed).pipe(
    mergeMap(() => this.service.retrieveusers())
)
```

I highly recommend taking a look at https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators

Answer (score 0):

that does not work because u are treading the this.users$ observable instead of emit a new value for the same observable.

The way to use BehaviourSubject to keep uptade the DOM is:

init the BehaviourSubject like this:

```
private MyBehaviourSubject = new BehaviourSubject(/*initial value here*/)

private MyBehaviourObservable = this.MyBehaviourSubject.asObservable()
```

So. To keep your view updateded you need to do in your template:

```
// with this your view always been refreshed after a new emission 
    {{MyBehaviourObservable | async }}
```

And to emit a new value you need to do something like this:

```
// when you do this your view will be updated.
    this.MyBehaviourSubject.next(/*new value here*/)
```